# Webpack - don't require a module when run clientside

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building a translation library that can be used serverside as well as clientside. Therefore, I must detect what the current environment is to require different modules:
On the client, translations need to be fetched via HTTP, on the server, I'll use `fs`. Running on the server, I check for the existence of the `window` object, which works flawlessly. Now I thought using the `definePlugin` to define `process.env.isClient = 'true'` should strip out the server code when the library is bundled with webpack, but it doesn't.
Searching around the web it seems like dual-use libraries are not so common with webpack. Is there any elegant solution for the problem?

Comment: When you use the Define plugin, the server code depending will only be stripped out when you minify your code, e.g. using the Uglify plugin. Are you using that?

Comment: @PatrickHund Yup, I do. Ironically, the module I tested the setup with was the `debug` module which is conditionally replaced by a `console.debug` call on the client side - so while testing if the debug logging works correctly, I run in debug mode and have Uglify disabled...  
That clears things up and makes sense. I'll see if I can add a custom Uglify config while debugging that'll only strip out static conditionals. Thanks!